# Serve protected media files with django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, nginx, nginx-location

I'd like Django to serve some media files (e.g. user-uploaded files) only for logged-in users. Since my site is quite low-traffic, I think I will keep things simple and do not use `django-sendfile` to tell Nginx when to serve a file. Instead I'll let Django/Gunicorn do the job. To me this seems a lot simpler and for a low traffic site this maybe more secure.

But what is the best way to organize the file storage location? Media files are all stored below `MEDIA_ROOT` and this directory is served by Nginx in production. If I upload my files to `MEDIA_ROOT/protected/` I have to tell Nginx not to serve the files in the subdirectory `protected`.

But is this a good idea? It seems a litte risky to me to allow Nginx access `/media/` in the first place and then protect the subdirectory `/media/protected/`. Wouldn't it be better not to use a subdirectory of `MEDIA_ROOT` to store protected files?

But if I try something like this quick-and-dirty in my model:

```
upload_to='../protected/documents/%Y/%m/'
```

Django complains:

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /admin/core/document/add/
The joined path (/home/me/projects/project/protected/documents/2016/09/test.file) is located outside of the base path component (/home/me/projects/project/media)
```

So I thing it is not good practice to "leave" the `MEDIA_ROOT`.

What is the best solution to store and serve protected media files?

Comment: See [`django-downloadview`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-downloadview).

Answer (score 14):

Serving media files ( that may be large files) from view directly is not good. You can use `sendfile` extension available in nginx server; a sample nginx configuration is like below.

```
 location /projects/project/media/{
    # this path is not public
    internal;
    # absolute path
    alias /projects/project/media/;
 }
```

change your view to

```
@login_required
def serve_protected_document(request, file):
    document = get_object_or_404(ProtectedDocument, file="protected/documents/" + file)

    # Split the elements of the path
    path, file_name = os.path.split(file)

    response = HttpResponse()
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + file_name
    # nginx uses this path to serve the file
    response["X-Accel-Redirect"] = document.name # path to file
    return response
```

Link: More details on configuring sendfile extension on nginx is [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/)

Comment: This isn't answering the question. It is about how you show the link on the form edit page.

Comment: The OP specified that the use case did not demand performance, and instead was looking for a simple implementation using the auth functions already in Django.

Comment: @surfer190 Spend some time on how a webserver handle requests compared to a WSGI application, then you will get an idea!

Comment: Note: You can also override the default Content-Type if you want nginx to determine one: `response["Content-Type"] = ""` (useful for example if you want to serve images directly not as an attachment)

Answer (score 12):

I now came up with the following solution:

I have this in my Django settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/projects/project/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/
```

In my models I do either:

```
document = models.FileField(upload_to="public/documents")
```

or

```
document = models.FileField(upload_to="protected/documents")
```

This way, I now have the two subdirectories 'public' and 'protected' in my media files directory.

Nginx or Djangos development server only serves the files in the 'public' subdirectory.

For Djangos development server:

```
if os.environ["ENVIRONMENT_TYPE"] == 'development':
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + "public/", document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "public/")
```

And for Nginx (used in production):

```
location /media/public/ {
    alias   /projects/project/media/public/;
}
```

When I want to serve a protected document, I do the following:

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^media/protected/documents/(?P<file>.*)$', core.views.serve_protected_document, name='serve_protected_document'),
```

And in views.py:

```
@login_required()
def serve_protected_document(request, file):
    document = get_object_or_404(ProtectedDocument, file="protected/documents/" + file)

    # Split the elements of the path
    path, file_name = os.path.split(file)

    response = FileResponse(document.file,)
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + file_name

    return response
```

I would appreciate any comments! Are there better ways to implement this?

Comment: I am looking for a solution to the same problem, except that I don't have any public media and that I wouldn't like misusing Django to serve files. But for the moment just one remark. Shouldn't file be opened before using File response?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects

Comment: @texnic  check my answer

Comment: Your views.py is not safe. If someone copy/pastes the url from source html, anyone should be able to download the file as long as they are logged in as anyone who has an account.

Answer (score 1):

Recently came into this problem with my django nuxt3 stack.

Since you can simply browse any file in MEDIA_FILES directory directly without any auth, it definitely is a huge security risk.

My Solution:
To protect ALL media files was to add to core/urls.py urlpatterns:

```
re_path(r'^media/(?:.*)$', MediaAuthChecker.as_view()),
```

This handles any requests to the backend that want to access the media folder. Other solutions was trying to create views per file, but as your project grows, having a APIView for all file types you might have, becomes very tedious.

Next problem was that in html, the `<img src="url/to/backend/media/file/location">` was doing their own "GET" requests to the backend and didn't include auth tokens or whatever method you are using to authenticate requests.

It would hit my MediaAuthChecker, but as an Anynomous user and be denied access immediately - very annoying!

So if you wanted to render protected files on your fronted, you need to do a separate GET request from your frontend and convert it in the correct format.

I created the nuxt3 composable to do just that:

```
export const download = async (api: string) => {
  runtimeConfig.public.isLoading = true; //loading bar
  try {    
    const response = await axios.get(api, { responseType: 'blob' });

    const fileDataUrl = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new window.FileReader();

      reader.onload = function() {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };

      reader.onerror = function(error) {
        reject(error);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(response.data);
    });

    runtimeConfig.public.isLoading = false; //loading bar

    return {status: 200, file: fileDataUrl}; // Return the image data URL
  } catch (error) {
    catchError(error);
  } finally {
    runtimeConfig.public.isLoading = false; //loading bar
  }
};
```

Then any file needing displaying:

JS:

```
resp = await download(fileUrl)
  if (resp.status === 200) {
    displayFile.value = resp.file
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <img v-if="displayFile" :src="displayFile" />
```

Tedious, but very effective in protecting your files.

Finally, the code for django MediaAuthChecker APIView to enable per media folder auth:

```
class MediaAuthChecker(APIView):
    """
        all my requests are login protected by default, 
        but you can add more permission classes if you want.
    """
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_path = request.get_full_path()[1:] #get requested file
        folders = file_path.split("/")[1:] #remove media initial folder and split into individual folders
        
        #is user permitted to view file? ### insert own auth methods here ###

        if folders[0] == "employees" and not request.user.check_groups("Employee"):
            return Response({'msg': "You are not authorized to view this resource."}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        
        if folders[0] == "group" and not request.user.check_groups("Rental Manager"):
            return Response({'msg': "You are not authorized to view this resource."}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        
        absolute_path = BASE_DIR / Path(file_path)
        try: #open and send file to frontend
            if os.path.exists(absolute_path):
                mime = MimeTypes()
                content_type, encoding = mime.guess_type(absolute_path)
                
                if content_type is None:
                    content_type = 'application/octet-stream'  # A default content type
                
                response = FileResponse(open(absolute_path, 'rb'), content_type=content_type)
                response['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline; filename="{os.path.basename(absolute_path)}"'
                return response
            else:
                return Response({'msg': "File not found."}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        except:
            return Response({'msg': "Error Processing File"}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Hopefully this inspires a few developers and hopefully somebody can refine it for me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

## project/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from .views import media_protect
urlpatterns = [
...
path('media/protect/<str:app>/<int:author>/<str:file>', media_protect)
...
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

## project/views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import FileResponse
from project import settings

@login_required
def media_protect(request, app, author, file):
    media_root = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    if ...:
        response = FileResponse(
            open(f'{media_root}/protect/{app}/{author}/{file}', 'rb'))
        return response
    else ...:
        retun ...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).