# Django static files protect access

Tags: django, authentication, url, required

Can i use `login_required` to get access to static files? For example if someone know url to static file, still can open this url even logged out. How can i resolve it? Could You give me any solutions how to protect my static files from not logged users.

```
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I would like to protect my media files

Comment: look at this question [Serve protected media files with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744587/serve-protected-media-files-with-django). Also look at this package [django-downloadview](https://github.com/jazzband/django-downloadview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this steps:

Step 1: All requests for media should go through a specific view

Step 2: Add the view and check access

Step 3: Configure your server

Check [here](https://b0uh.github.io/protect-django-media-files-per-user-basis-with-nginx.html) for more detail

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could You chcek my code - how i resolved problem? is it correct ?

Comment: Unfortunately ,I'm not expert in django sec

Answer (score 0):

Static files are open for public anyone can download it or copy your css code for example,

but  the only thing you can do is create a function that block any IP request the static file URL,

Answer (score -1):

However i resolved it in diffrent way. Could You tell me is correct and safe?

I removed media static from urls.py

```
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And added extra path url and function in views like below:

urls.py

```
path('media/client_images/<str:file>', login_required(clients_views.client_images), name='client_images'),
```

views.py

```
def client_images(request, file):
picture = get_object_or_404(Client_image, image='client_images/'+file)
path, file_name = os.path.split(file)
response = FileResponse(picture.image)
return response
```

Is it safe? I didn't change my nginx server configuration